# How to check calendar value is null or empty in xhtml attribute

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, xhtml, java.util.calendar

I have a column in my jsf page, i'm using primefaces dataTable:

e.g:

```
<p:column headerText="Last Trip End Time" width="100" rendered="#{selectedColumnsBeanForDPR.endTime and userBean.user.allowedFeatures.containsKey('LastTripEndTime')}" >
    <h:outputText value="#{car.dailyTrakingReportBean.endTime.time}" >
        <f:convertDateTime type="both" dateStyle="default" pattern="h:mm:ss a MM/dd/yyyy" />
    </h:outputText>
</p:column>
```

Now the issue is that when I have getting null value in 'endTime' Calendar variable its shows me empty column.
How can i show '--' when endTime is null?

Comment: you can use EL expression for checking null like `#{car.dailyTrakingReportBean.endTime eq null}` then `<h:outputText value="--" />`

Comment: I have already do this way but it show me : Could not convert 'false' to a string. this error

Comment: then post that piece of code. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a condition to check the value of endDate, when it's null you show "--" :

```
<h:outputText value="#{car.dailyTrakingReportBean.endTime.time == null ? '--' : car.dailyTrakingReportBean.endTime.time}" >
    <f:convertDateTime type="both" dateStyle="default" pattern="h:mm:ss a MM/dd/yyyy" />
</h:outputText>
```